# Controlling d3js pie animations and place labels inside pie

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm a complete noop to D3 and partly SVG, so I got a few basic questions.
First off, my code in question can be viewed at http://dotnetcarpenter.github.io/d3-test/ and I've used [Simple Pie Chart example with D3.js](https://gist.github.com/enjalot/1203641) and [Pie Chart Update, II](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) as examples to get a running start.

As you can see, the animation gets skewed in the end when the low path values switch to the higher values. This is obviously not what I want. I think I'm getting the order of calculations wrong but I'm not sure what to do. I'm using the code from the last example:

```
function change() {
  //...
  path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
}
// where arcTween is
function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

Another issue is placing labels on the sectors. I've put the update stuff in the change function and is able to read out and only render them if the value is between 0 and 100. I can't however place them in any way. Looking at the first example, I figure that I could do something like this:

```
text.data(data)
    .text(setText)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      // we have to make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
      d.innerRadius = 0;
      d.outerRadius = radius;
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle") //center the text on it's origin
```

Where text is a d3 selection and arc is: `d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius)`
But I get "*Unexpected value translate(NaN,NaN) parsing transform attribute.*" warning in Firefox and the labels are written on top of each other.

I appreciate any help and hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

#### Maintain sector order throughout an animation.

You'd be forgiven for thinking that [object contancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) had something do with it. I did. But it turns out to be much simpler than that.

Every pie chart is by default sorted by value. If you don't want to sort by value but e.g. by data list order, you just have to disable sorting.

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie() // get a pie object structure
            .value(function(d) { // define how to get your data value
                return d.value;  // (based on your data set)
            })
            .sort(null); // disable sort-by-value
```

#### Positioning labels according to your chart

Basically, you need to calculate your label positions depending on the type of chart or graph, your trying to connect them to. In my case, it's a pie chart. So if I want d3 to help with the calculations, I need to tell [centroid](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-arc_centroid) the **inner** and **outer radius** and, most importantly to my issue, the **start** and **end angles**. The latter was missing from my code. Getting these values is as simple as, calling our pie layout above with our dataset and then do a *transform*.
<sub>Note that you don't have to call `.data()` again if you created the SVG with d3 and already supplied your data wrapped in `.pie()` structure. That is, that you didn't select any existing SVG from your page.</sub>

```
var svg =  d3.select("svg")
             // do stuff with your svg
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
             // set stuff on your layout
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
              .data(pie(dataset)) // where dataset contains your data
              .attr("transform", function(d) {
                                     return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                                 });
```

I have to give credit to Philip Pedruco for [helping me](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/iV6_B1tF45A) along the way.

### Bonus info

Use *viewBox* if you want to position your SVG cross browser, not *transform/translate*.

```
// move pie to center
d3.select("svg").attr("viewBox", -radius + ","+ -radius +"," + size + "," + size)
```